# C-statistic and measuring the contextual effect in multilevel logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, auc

I have a two-level logistic regression model where the outcome is "InfectedqPCR" (Plasmodium-infected as determined by qPCR) at the individual level.

I have a range of individual- and household-level variables.
Household is the grouping structure.

I have been reading Austin and Merlo's (2017) **"Intermediate and advanced topics in multilevel logistic regression analysis"** Tutorial in Biostatistics - *Statistics in Medicine* - about using the c-statistic as a measure of the magnitude of the general contextual effect.

Following their methods, I am trying to interpret the c-statistic output from the following three models:

```r
model1 <- glm(Infected_qPCR ~ Sex + Age_Band_Years, family="binomial", 
              data=Data_Model_In_Adults)
Cstat(x = predict(model1), 
      resp = model.response(model.frame(model1))) # 0.653
      # Contains only fixed effects - no random effect structure
Cstat(x = predict(Mod_MAd_Indi), 
      resp = model.response(model.frame(Mod_MAd_Indi))) # 0.823
      # Contains the same fixed effects (Sex and Age_Band_Years) and 
      # the household clustering random effect
Cstat(x = predict(Mod_MAd_Comb_Vil), 
      resp = model.response(model.frame(Mod_MAd_Comb_Vil))) # 0.771
      # Contains the same individual fixed effects (Sex and 
      # Age_Band_Years) and various household factors and the 
      # household clustering random effect
```

So, from this, I interpret that the change in the c-statistic from model1 with only fixed effects and no random effect structure to Mod_MAd_Indi, which includes the random effect structure, is 0.17.

In the Austin and Merlo paper, their example has a change in the c-statistic of 0.004, which indicates a "weak general contextual effect".

**Question 1:**

So, if 0.004 is weak, what can I say if my contextual effect is 0.17? Is this a moderate contextual effect or a strong effect? Are there any guidelines or references for this?

**Question 2:**

The Austin and Merlo paper also emphasises that "the addition of cluster characteristics to the model that contains cluster-specific random effects cannot increase the c-statistic of the model containing only the cluster-specific random effects." So, is this 0.17 change in the c-statistic the maximum possible change - what Austin and Merlo refer to as "a ceiling"? Is this why my addition of the household variables (Mod_MAd_Comb_Vil) resulted in a lower c-statistic? It could have been the same or lower, but definitely not higher - is that what Austin and Merlo are meaning?

**This is an addition following on from the helpful input of Eric Ruzek in the comments below:**

In a further series of models, I have a C-statistic that has increased, only at the second decimal place, but nevertheless, it has increased after including household-level variables in the model.

- In the individual (and random effects) model, it is 0.880
- In the household and individual (and random effects) model, it is 0.892.

This seems to go against all statistical intuition, but might the following explain this?

**The individual model is as follows:**

```r
Mod_Indi_Child_0.05_Apriori <- glmer(Infected_qPCR ~ 1 + 
      Age_Band_Years + Work_Place_Nearby_Forest + Bednet_last_night +
      (1 | Household_ID.x), data = Data_Model_In_Child, 
      family = binomial, glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

**The combined model is as follows:**

```r
Mod_Comb_Child_Apriori <- glmer(Infected_qPCR ~ 1 + Age_Band_Years + 
    Work_Place_Nearby_Forest + Bednet_last_night + 
    scale(Persons_living_in_house_count, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)  
    + (1 | Household_ID.x), data = Data_Model_In_Child, 
    family = binomial, glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

The difference between the two models is the addition of the "Household-level" factor (Number of persons in the house count) in the combined model. Could the reason why this model has a higher C-statistic than the individual-only model be because this "household level" level factor actually contains information at the individual level as well? By that, I mean because the variable is "Numeber of persons living in the house", the individual is part of that house count, so the model is treating at least part of that "house count" as an individual-level variable, hence the rise in the C-statistic.

Is this a possible explanation for the unusual result I have, or am clutching at straws?

Comment: I cannot speak to question 1. Regarding question 2, I think that the .17 is the max possible change because level 2 predictors will have the effect of decreasing the level 2 variance. This statement assumes that the C-statistic declines as the level 2 variance declines.

Comment: @ErikRuzek Thank you, this makes sense and fits with the explanation in the Austin and Merlo paper. But, is it possible that level two variables might not decrease the level two variance, i.e., that they actually increase the variance - even slightly? I am just throwing this out there because I have another series of models where the C-statisitc has increased, only at the second decimal place (0.880 to .892), but nevertheless, it has increased. It this mathematically possible?

Comment: Ordinarily, I would not expect a level 2 variable to increase the level 2 variance. It is possible that a level 1 variable, which has both within- and between-cluster effects, could increase the L2 variance rather than reduce it. See https://www.statmodel.com/download/Level-2%20R-square%20decreasing%20when%20adding%20level1-covariate.pdf

Comment: Is this C statistic the concordance index (which equals area under the ROC curve in this particular situation)?

Comment: @Dave Yes; the Austin and Merlo paper referred to above suggests using this as a measure of the overall contextual effect in multi-level models, specifically the change in C-statistic (discriminatory power).

Comment: For what it’s worth, Frank Harrell, developer of the c-index, has a dim view of using c-index to compare models. He has written about that on here many times.

Comment: @Dave - Thank you for pointing this out - I will investigate and return to the drawing board.

Comment: I still have a dim view of that :-) as the c-index is not sensitive enough for that purpose.